# How to flip or invert an equality check

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a function and would like to be able to change the equality check with a parameter so that for one version I extract all items that equal x, and for the other version all the items that do not equal x.

Here is my function:

```
Public Function GetAllItemsByUserName(ByVal userName As String) As List(Of MyRecords)
    Dim itemsQuery = From myRecord as MyRecord from _ListOfRecords
                     Where myRecord.Name = userName
                     Select myRecord
    Return itemsQuery.ToList
End Function
```

So I would like to just flip the equality using a parameter so that I can extract either all records that = username, or all those that != username. Is there a way of doing this without writing two versions of the function?

Comment: Do you want do do this in C# too? You've tagged for both languages but only written code in VB

Comment: An answer in either language would be most excellent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the [`If`(conditional) operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) in the `Where`:

```
Public Function GetAllItemsByUserName(ByVal userName As String, equals As Boolean) As List(Of MyRecords)
    Dim itemsQuery = 
        From myRecord In _ListOfRecords
        Where If(equals, myRecord.Name = userName, myRecord.Name <> userName)
        Select myRecord
    Return itemsQuery.ToList
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Xor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/csw1x2a6.aspx) (Exclusive Or) operator.

```
Public Function GetAllItemsByUserName(ByVal userName As String, ByVal exclude As Boolean) As List(Of MyRecords)
    Dim itemsQuery = From myRecord as MyRecord from _ListOfRecords
                     Where (myRecord.Name = userName) Xor exclude
                     Select myRecord
    Return itemsQuery.ToList
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly for my situation and I've learned about the Xor operator

Comment: I actually ended up using a combination of Tim and Henriks answer which is why I've moved the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetAllItemsByUserName(ByVal userName As String, ByVal equal as Boolean) As List(Of MyRecords)
    Dim itemsQuery = From myRecord as MyRecord from _ListOfRecords
                     Where (myRecord.Name = userName) = equal
                     Select myRecord
    Return itemsQuery.ToList
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way this could be achieved:

```
Public Function GetAllItemsByUserName(ByVal userName As String, equals As Boolean) As List(Of MyRecords)
    Dim itemsQuery = From myRecord as MyRecord from _ListOfRecords
                     Where (equals && myRecord.Name = userName) Or (!equals && myRecord.Name != userName)
                     Select myRecord
    Return itemsQuery.ToList
End Function
```